# datagrid.ItemsSource = datatable.AsDataView(); Equivalent in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a project in WPF with XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid  >
    <DataGrid Name="datagrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" >
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And the `.cs` file as following:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public DataTable dt;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Group", typeof(int));
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[3] { "Mary", 22, 1 });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[3] { "Peter", 24, 3 });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[3] { "Rose", 17, 1 });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[3] { "John", 19, 2 });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[3] { "Steven", 20, 1 });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[3] { "Tom", 20, 3 });
        datagrid1.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
        //DataContext = dt.AsDataView(); 
    }
}
```

I just want to move the code `datagrid1.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();` to XAML.

Answer (score 1):

you can cast DataTable to generic collection using DataTable.AsEnumerable() and give this as  Source to CollectionViewSource.

like-

IEnumerable YourType> vr = YourDataTable.AsEnumerable();

CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding vr}">

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a `DependencyProperty` that holds your `DataView`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataViewProperty = DependencyProperty.
    Register("DataView", typeof(DataView), typeof(MainWindow));

public DataView DataView
{
    get { return (DataView)GetValue(DataViewProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DataViewProperty, value); }
}
```

Set this property:

```
DataView = dt.AsDataView();
```

Then you need to bind to this in your UI:

```
<DataGrid Name="datagrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding DataView, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MainWindow}}}" />
```

That's it.

Comment: getting error at  <DataGrid Name="datagrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding DataView, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MainWindow}}}" />

Comment: @vinayswargam, I couldn't see the difference at first and was wondering why you had shown me my code example... found the missing `}` eventually though... thanks.

Comment: the type reference cannot find a public type named "MainWindow"

Comment: Thanks Sheridan for reply

Comment: The error is the type reference cannot find a public type named "MainWindow"

Comment: Do you understand it now? Replace `MainWindow` with the name of your view class... I just assumed that your were using `MainWindow.xaml`.

Comment: Why use a `DependencyProperty` instead of a public property and INPC?

Comment: It is just less code to show and it means that I didn't have to explain the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to *another* new user.

Comment: Do you need to set the `Binding Mode` to `Two-Way` if you're using a `DependencyProperty`?

Comment: Nope. The `Binding` in the example will allow the UI to be updated from the property and the property from the UI as it is.